# Java Theory: Classes Design for Currency, Futures and Metals Analysis

Tags: java, theory

Personal Project looking for the top level OOP theory on how to design my 
program from a Class point of view in Java for data manipulation of the following:

1. Have multiple historical Data stored as CSV files. (nothing else).
2. Historical Data is located on harddrive.
3. Historical data consists of the following types: 
    a. Currencies (multiple currencies) all the same format.
    b. Futures (multiple futures) different tick format than Currencies.
    c. Metals (multiple metals) Same tick format as Currencies.
4. Want to perform the following type of data manipulation through methods
   a. Common Statistical Analysis on all the historical data.
   b. Specific own algorithms analysis on the historical data.
5. Results of the above in table format

I started this on futures data and writing methods etc but I was very procedural like,
for example:
Just had 2 classes, one was with all my methods and the other was just a test class which called the methods through an object I created.
I kept on calling my same array that stored my tickdata for each of the procedures which was not very efficient.
I would like to use the principals of inheritance, polymorphism code reuse etc to do this.

At the moment I am not concerned with speed,performance etc but just being able to do it
from a programming point of view. I am very new to this and i think this is the best way to learn it.
If I was being able to do it on a couple of gigs of data that would be great!
My system has 12 gigs of memory.

Any help would be great!

Comment: An object is roughly a state, a set of methods and a behavior emerging from methods chain... Post your procedural code to have hints.

Comment: What is the question exactly? Are you asking us to give you a precise design for your program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your classes**

> a) Currencies (multiple currencies) all the same format.
>   b) Futures (multiple futures) different tick format than Currencies.
>   c) Metals (multiple metals) Same tick format as Currencies.

There's three classes there. You can have some class `Currency`, `Futures` and `Metals`. These are all under the category of `HistoricalData`. For example:

```
public class Currency extends HistoricalData
{
    private String data;

    public Currency(String data)
    {
        // Just a mock up.
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

If you think that you will be making a lot of changes to your statistical analysis, then you don't want to have to make those changes in every class that you implement some `statistics` method in. This hints to me, that you should probably port that to a `HistoryStatsEngine` (or whatever) class. That way you can make changes to how the classes are used without changing the classes themselves.

**Using those classes**

*Substitutability*

Because all the classes are all subclasses of the `HistoricalData` supertype, you can create a collection that contains all of them, like:

```
private ArrayList<HistoricalData> data = new ArrayList<HistoricalData>();
```

*Abstract Methods*

In your `HistoricalData` class, you can have the necessary abstract methods, for example:

```
public void performCalculation();
```

Comment: thank you, that is exactly the type of setup I am looking for. I am going to try this setup now and will post back.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there's an upcoming JSR called 'java-money': http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=354 (https://github.com/JavaMoney)

Unfortunately, that's not officially available yet, so might want to go with another framework for now: https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-money

Comment: I didn't know they were finally doing a Money class! That's good, what's there is borked. Thanks +1 for passing on useful information...

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the idea of a base class just to prevent duplicating methods. How is a Currency an HistoricalData? What does that say about it? Nothing.

This is a tough problem that many programmers never get good at, good for you for wanting to drive into traffic on this one and not just produce procedural goo.

You don't really say what kind of statistical analysis you want to do. I have done a lot of work with probability. Probabilistic models revolve around the notion of aggregating 'features' into classifications and then predicting the future by seeing which classifier new instances most closely resemble. If I were going to construct a logical model, for instance, to guess what was going to happen with Futures that I knew about, I would build a classifier. Most likely there would be two classifications representing which ones succeeded and which failed, then I would train on my past data. Training involves extracting the values for each feature and putting them into the classification's distribution. Pretty simple. And you would not want a base class, and you for sure don't want the classifications in the type hierarchy. Then once I have trained the classifiers, I can compute the probability of success for a new Future by simply computing its likeness to the two classification, using a trade off band to decide which one to choose (or neither).

It's always a bad idea to start building analytic artifacts into a type hierarchy because analysis is by definition perspectival: tomorrow I might want to do something completely different with the same types, or test them for a totally different case, e.g. predict which Futures are fraudulent.

Comment: *Historical data consists of the following types:*. OP specifically defined `Currency` as a type of historical data.

Comment: @Rob I really need to look into what classification is etc. New to this so I am starting from the bottom up. thanks for the reply!

Comment: @ Chris, agree, my 3 types of Historical Data are Currency, Futures and Metals. I receive Currency and Metals in the same format each time. So my parsing method will be the same for these types. However the Futures data is different so my parsing method for this will be similar but different. Within my currency type i will have multiple currencies ex eurusd, eurgbp etc, within futures i will have es, nq etc metals example xagusd, xauusd..

Comment: @ChrisCooney so? Later when his model is also considering what the temperature was that day or what cycle the moon was in, would that extend HistoricalData? Would in your solution. Applying isa to that is silly. Everything is historical data. You are supposed to use inheritance when isa means something, like isa Cow an Animal? or a Mammal?